# Guardar ultimo cambio commit y hacer push

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Bueno quiza esto sea básico espero puedan ayudarme, hice un pull hace unos dias a mi local, despues agregue un par de modificaciones y hoy hice un commit con mi ultimos cambios, despues hice un push, pero no se subieron los últimos cambios, se subieron otros (los de origin), y bueno lo que quiero es hacer push de mis ultimos(ultimo commit) cambios, alguna idea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

antes hice un git push, pero me votaba un mensaje en consola:
e hice un git push origin test -f

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Los cambios fueron a las misma rama?
Verificaste que al subir los cambios la rama remota no tenia actualizaciones?

Comment: Fue en la misma rama, donde hice esto, dias antes hice pull de la rama rosa que es donde tenia cambios, y hoy hice el commit y depsues el push pero me aparecio un msj de consola donde decia .Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote, y utlice git push origin test -f

Comment: Intenta hacer primero `git pull --rebase origin test` para actualizar la rama local y despues hacer el `push`

Comment: Si me salio un conflicto de una linea duplicada, y ya lo corregi ejecuto de nuevo git pull --rebase origin test? este ya se posiciono en el punto rosa en el ultimo commit, hago el push o ejecuto de nuevo pull?

Comment: Revisa que ya esté actualizada la rama y después el push

Comment: Me funciono tu respuesta muchas gracias, ya quedo, podrías poner tu respuesta para seleccionarla como mejor respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta hacer primero `git pull --rebase origin test` para actualizar la rama local y después hacer el `push`

Comment: Gracias crack!!